# ODBC Linked Tables Convert Tinyint Fields to Yes/No

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm in the process of converting an Access .ADP project to a .ACCDB with linked tables. I know that a big issue when working with a SQL Server backend is the use of nullable `bit` fields, since Access's `Yes/No` data type doesn't allow for nulls. So I converted all of my nullable `bit` fields to `tinyint`. However, Access is still mapping these fields as `Yes/No`, and converting all of my nulls to zeroes.

Does anyone have any advice for how to get it to stop this? I've double-checked that the fields in question are set to `tinyint`, and querying in SSMS I see that the vast majority of the records are null. But all I can think to do is refresh or remove and recreate the linked table, and that's not fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my case is something I should have remembered, but slipped my mind. Hopefully it will be helpful to someone else in the future.

My linked tables are actually linked to views on the backend (something I definitely should have mentioned in my question). The metadata on a view [is not automatically refreshed](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/pkumar3/ssas/2703/sql-server-views-some-great-views-about-views) when the underlying tables change. I had changed all of the nullable `bit` fields in my underlying tables to `tinyint`, but as far as the views were concerned, they were still `bit`.

Last night, I dropped and recreated all of my views, then refreshed the linked tables in Access. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I have had much more luck using nullable int fields storing -1 (for Yes), 0 (for No) and null (Don't know/undefined). Access forms understand these values perfectly and they respond correctly when bound to checkboxes and used for filtering etc. Nulls (which you can do with native Access tables btw if you set Required property to No) will be greyed out when bound to checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm only binding to option groups, not checkboxes, so I wouldn't think this would matter, but I'll give it a try in the morning.